# Combination Probability with the word EQUALITY

Tags: combinatorics

Question: Use the word EQUALITY to answer the following questions.  Four letter words are formed with no letters used more than once.

A. How many four letter words can be formed?

B. How many contain at least two consonants?

My Solutions:

Solution A:

8 C 4 * 4! = 1680

Solution B: I am not sure about this one so here is my approach.

At last 2 consonants means 2 or 3 or 4 consonants.

2 Consonants: (4 C 2) * (4 C 2) * 4!

3 Consonants: (4 C 3) * (4 C 1) * 4!

4 Consonants: (4 C 4) * (4 C 0) * 4!

Finally we add them together:

(4 C 2) * (4 C 2) * 4! + (4 C 3) * (4 C 1) * 4! + (4 C 4) * (4 C 0) * 4! = 1272

Is this correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your answer for A and B are both correct, but I'll introduce to you the concept of complimentary counting. For Problem B you could instead count the number of four letter words with $0$ or $1$ consonants and subtract their sum from the total ($1680$) to get the answer.

Case $1$: $0$ Consonants

Since there are $4$ consonants and $4$ vowels, the number of ways to choose the $4$ letter words is basically 4 C 4 times $4!$ which is $24$.

Case $2$: $1$ Consonant

There is 4 C 1 number of ways to choose the $1$ cosonant times 4 C 3 ways to choose the vowels, all multiplied $4!$, which is $4\cdot4\cdot24$ which is $384$.

$384+24=408$

$1680-408=1272$

Comment: Wow, this is a much easier way to think about the problem and also easier math.  I'll try and remember the concept of complimentary counting going forward.  Thank you!